# Should I reuse one instance of GSON or create new ones on demand?

Tags: java, json, gson

In most of my classes (especially server resources) I tend to create new instances of `com.google.gson.Gson` on demand. Sometimes I create them with the default constructor (for handling of simple POJOs), sometimes I use more sophisticated variants created with custom `com.google.gson.GsonBuilder`.

I know that `Gson` is a threadsafe class, so there is nothing standing against reusing the same instance of `Gson` instead of creating new ones. Heck, I might even reuse a static constant for this!

My question is this: should I create new instances whenever I need them, or should I create and use just one? What sort of performance implications will I be facing, if I serialize simple POJO with a `Gson` instance that was created with `GsonBuilder` and taught how to parse more complex data structures (had few custom serializers being registered)?

Comment: I would consider **correctness** and **readability** before **performance**. Unless you have reliable benchmarks that prove that `Gson` instance creation is a bottleneck, in which case you can sacrifice some of the readability for performance.

Comment: @biziclop, I totally agree with your remarks but I don't see how this comment applies here. It's purely about calling `new Gson()` each time or wrapping it up with a static reference like `JsonUtils.GSON` or singleton `DefaultGson.instance()`.

Comment: I slightly misread your question and I thought you were going to cache multiple `Gson` objects, where thread safety (correctness) would've been a factor. Sorry. (I don't know `Gson` in any great detail but in similar situations I tend to go for the single instance solution if that helps. Makes things a lot simpler.)

Comment: Retrofit uses a cached version of Gson in the `GsonConverterFactory` so I'm leaning towards the idea that this is better than creating a new one each time.

Comment: I've been actually doing this for quite a lot time now and I've never ran into any issues. It also helps a lot to have a fixed set of adapters/serializers which is easier to maintain if you only have one instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is an old question but for future reference, the answer to this question is that you should go for the single instance if it is possible.

The creation of a GSON object is expensive depending on how many custom deserializer/serializer/handlers you register to it. I doubt that you will see any big performance boost from this.

About the second question, GSON internally has a list of registered serializer, and each one is checked against the object you are trying to parse. So you basically will add more iterations each time you register a custom serializer, but again, this is not a big performance issue compared to having a couple of big clumsy objects into memory.

Comment: Your answer does not make sense - "The creation ... is expensive ... I doubt that you will see any big performance boost from this". You seem to be contradicting yourself. Also in the last line of the 3rd paragraph it gets a bit confusing.

Comment: Please read the whole sentence: "is expensive DEPENDING on how many...". It means that more objects = more expensive. Also I don't get what you don't understand on the last sentence.

Comment: Hi, thx - What are we seeing or not seeing the performance boost from? Last line says registering custom serializers adds more iterations, which is not a big issue compared to keeping objects in memory - so are you saying we should keep the objects in memory, or not? Relate that to your first line that says we should go with the single instance if possible - even though that may mean having "a couple of big clumsy object in memory".

Comment: fwiw I do agree to cache gson - just don't follow the logic in the answer.